# PowerPoint SlideShowSettings.Run() does not run embedded video

Tags: c#, powerpoint, slideshow, movie, embedded-video

I have a C# application that runs on a computer connected to a large display in our cafeteria.  The application pulls all the PowerPoint files out of a folder and runs each one as a slide show continuously.  Everything was working fine until someone decided to insert a movie clip onto a slide.  The problem is that the movie never starts.  If open the presentation in PowerPoint and run the show it works, and if I right click on the presentation and click 'show' it works.  Here is the code I am using to open the presentation and start the slideshow.

```
pres = app.Presentations.Open(pptPath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MMsoTriState.msoFals);
pres.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```

Is there something else I need to set to get the `Run()` method to also start movies?

**Edit:** The presentation in question only had one slide in it which contained the movie.  If I added another slide to it, it worked fine.  Also tried adding a slide before and had the same problem, so apparently the problem only exists for the last slide in the presentation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the problem.  I had a `thread.sleep` statement in the presentation's `app_SlideShowNextSlide` event handler that handled the end of one slideshow and starting the next.  I wasn't thinking at the time and this code was running in the same thread at the slideshow itself.  I created a timer object instead and moved the necessary code into the timer's `elapsed` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that PowerPoint animations (video, audio, custom motion paths, etc.) will only play when the `SlideShowWindow` has the focus. What this means is that when you're running your app and launching PPT, your app still maintains the focus and hence animations don't run (that doesn't stop you from manually manipulating your running deck though).

There are a couple of ways around this:

1. You can call the API `SetWindow` to
   bring your `SlideShowWindow` to the
   front. Not a great way to do it in
   my opinion.
2. The very easiest way is just to save
   your .ppt/.pptx to a .pps/.ppsx
   (PowerPoint Show). With that, you
   can use your same code to run it and
   it will launch and take the focus
   automatically (and your animations [video, et al) will run as you've intended).

Comment: It is already set to play automatically. If I run the slideshow manually everything works. I only have a problem when I run the slideshow using the code in the question and the movie is on the last slide of the presentation.

Comment: @AdmSteck. Okay, understood. I've got some good news and bad news for you. Answer has been updated.